# Any way to prevent from re declaring variable in js jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code structure.

````
<!-- first.tpl -->
<script>
   ``` 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        objIns.loadNames = '{$names|json_encode}';
     }
    )
   ```
</script>
{include file="second.tpl"}
<!-- end of first.tpl -->

<!-- second.tpl -->
some code here
<script>
```
$(document).ready(function() {
    objIns.loadNames = '{$names|json_encode}';
})
```
</script>
````

My question is that why do I required to declared variable **objIns.loadNames** in second.tpl file since it already loaded in first.tpl file? Any way that not to redeclare this variable in second.tpl. I tried it by declaring the "var" keyword but it won't work.

Comment: is `objIns` a global variable?

Comment: Add: var objIns; at the top. It must be global to do what you want.

Comment: @brk yes I have not used var so it should treat as global variable as per my understandings.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by making **objIns** as a global variable.

```
<script>
var objIns;
$(document).ready(function() {
objIns.loadNames = '{$names|json_encode}';
</script>
{include file="second.tpl"}
```

Declaring variables inside the function will make there scope local, so declare variables outside the function so that it can be used globally.

Answer (score 0):

Define your `objIns variable before $(document).ready function in first.tpl file as global`

```
var objIns='';
```

**OR**

Use `javascript localstorage` in `first.tpl` file

**Add these lines inside document ready function**

```
objIns.loadNames = '{$names|json_encode}';
localStorage.setItem("objIns",objIns.loadNames);
```

In first.tpl file

**Access storagedata in second.tpl**

```
localStorage.getItem("objIns");
```

More about js localstorage [click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)